# Blender not runninng

Tags: permissions, blender

I just downloaded the latest Blender version and it is not running when I double-click it or run it through the terminal. The only way to run the application is to call it as super user and even when it is opened I cannot install certain plugins due to the current permission configured for the executable file. Some of the purchased plugins that I tried to install crash Blender during the installation which wasn't happening before.

Here is the output from the terminal after trying to run it:

```
user@group:~/Downloads/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64$ ./blender
Read prefs: /path/.config/blender/3.0/config/userpref.blend
Registered MACHIN3tools 0.9.0 with 1 tool, 1 pie menu
Registered MESHmachine 0.10.0 with 2 plug libraries
 • plug library: Examples
 • plug library: MyPlugs
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, everytime I try opening the application it crashes and creates a new file in the coredump folder. Is it ok to delete them from that folder?

I'm somewhat new to Linux and don't want to mess around with the permissions myself using `chmod` or `chown` as I learned it the hard way when learning about `chmod 777` and had to re-install Linux.

That said, how can I permanently run Blender without having to do so as super user since the plugins will not install properly without the right permission?

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output when you try to run it from terminal?

Comment: To clarify, run the command `blender` in a terminal. Then [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391873/edit) the question and post the output between three back-ticks, to format it as `code`.

Comment: Did you even install the software? From your description, it sounds like you are trying to double-click a file you downloaded. That won't work. Blender is available in official repos, just run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install blender`. Alternatively, you can also install the snap which will typically have a newer version. Just run `sudo snap install blender --classic`.

Comment: Checking the official Blender manual, it says to extract the tar.xz file and run the executable. Blender automatically creates a folder in the .config folder with all the user prefs and application files. It is pretty straight forward these days but one can also use the terminal to do so. I could finally find a way to run it again by deleting this folder: $HOME/.config/blender/3.0/. It deletes all user preferences though. However, unfortunately, one of the plugins that I use is still crashing Blender when I try to install it.

Comment: @RivalConsoles There is an official version that is designed for your particular version of Ubuntu available from the Ubuntu repository which is similar to the "play store" on Android or the Apple "app store". All you have to do is run `sudo apt update` and then run `sudo apt install blender`. The maintainers work out the bugs before it's released so you don't have to deal with these crashes.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official version that is designed for your particular version of Ubuntu available from the Ubuntu repository which is similar to the "play store" on Android or the Apple "app store". All you have to do is open a terminal and then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt install blender
```

The maintainers work out the bugs before it's released so you don't have to deal with these crashes.

Unlike Windows, we don't typically download and install software from random websites. Most available software is available from the Ubuntu repositories. To search for software, you can open the Gnome Software application (sometimes called the Software Center) or you can search for available software using the `apt-cache search` command. This will show you available packages related to your search.

For example, to search for blender, run the following command:

```
apt-cache search blender
```

This will show a list of available packages with brief descriptions.

To narrow your search, you can limit the results that only include "blender" by using `grep` like this:

```
apt-cache search blender | grep -i blender
```

Also, you can run `apt-cache show` to gain more information about a package.

```
apt-cache show blender
```

Scroll down to read the Description section.

Again, to install a package, first update your package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then install the package:

```
sudo apt install blender
```

Alternatively, you can also install packages from the Ubuntu repositories by using the Gnome Software application, also called the Ubuntu Software Center. This uses a GUI and has more of a "play store" feel but it's really just a frontend for `apt` and `snap`.

Lastly, if you want to install a package, and it is not available through the Ubuntu repositories, then you should check for a downloadable version from the software source. However, this is rarely necessary as Ubuntu contains tens of thousands of packages more than any other linux based distro aside from Debian (or Ubuntu derivatives).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem with the blender version manually installed from the download provided on Blender's website. The solution was to delete the Blender folder from this path:

`~/.config/blender/3.0`

It seems that the issue was lying in the user folder. By removing Blender's application folder under `~/.config/`, Blender is now running without any issues.

Comment: Alright, thanks @Nmath.